# Can I cast the spell of a spell storing melee weapon thrown?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, damage

[Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/spell-storing) [storing](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spell%20Storing) is a Magic Weapon Special Ability which can only be placed on melee weapons:

> A *spell storing* weapon allows a spellcaster to store a single targeted spell of up to 3rd level in the weapon. (The spell must have a casting time of 1 standard action.) Anytime the weapon strikes a creature and the creature takes damage from it, the weapon can immediately cast the spell on that creature as a free action if the wielder desires. (This special ability is an exception to the general rule that casting a spell from an item takes at least as long as casting that spell normally.) Once the spell has been cast from the weapon, a spellcaster can cast any other targeted spell of up to 3rd level into it. The weapon magically imparts to the wielder the name of the spell currently stored within it. A randomly rolled spell storing weapon has a 50% chance of having a spell stored in it already. **This special ability can only be placed on melee weapons.**

[source](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spell%20Storing) *emphasis mine*

Some melee weapon can be thrown:

> Melee weapons are used for making melee attacks, **though some of them can be thrown as well**. Ranged weapons are thrown weapons or projectile weapons that are not effective in melee.

[source](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/) *emphasis mine*

A dagger is a melee weapon. So I can have a spell storing dagger. A dagger can be thrown.

So my 5th level 14-strength magus throws my throw-able spell storing dagger stored with a Shocking Grasp. The attack passes. Does the spell cast? The dagger deals 1d4 piercing + 2 from str + 5d6 electricity, doesn't it?

---

Edit following comments

> Anytime the weapon strikes a creature and the creature takes damage from it, the weapon can immediately cast the spell on that creature as a free action if the wielder desires.

What is the wielder? The problem is that "wield" is used as just a word and not a game term. Their no official ruling nor FAQ about that (as per a [discussion](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qwgx&page=2?Can-we-get-an-official-definition-for-wielding) shared by @Hey I Can Chan)

In our case, does the character is still wielding after the weapon is thrown? While I have the weapon in hand, can I chose to activate the spell on damage?

Comment: RE: "'[T]he [*spell storing*] weapon can immediately cast the spell on that creature as a free action if the wielder desires."' Has the GM already ruled that a weapon, once thrown, is, indeed, still wielded? Or is that the question?

Comment: @HeyICanChan it is part of the question yes.

Comment: [See here.](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qwgx&page=1?Can-we-get-an-official-definition-for-wielding)

Comment: @HeyICanChan ok. The problem is that "wield" is used as just a word and not a game term. Would you write a clean answer resuming this discussion?

Comment: @HeyICanChan From the SRD: "Thrown Weapons: The _wielder_ applies his Strength modifier..."

Comment: I'm not sure what I could add to a discussion that already runs nearly 200 posts… *and* remains inconclusive. That's why I asked if the GM had ruled—I don't think there *is* an official ruling. However, I've not made that an answer because I haven't done any recent research on wielding. It's possible that near the end of *Pathfinder* a developer or text made it clear what *wielding* means but that I'm unaware of it. (I mainly wanted to make those who were considering answers aware that a lot of words have already been spent on essentially saying, "Ask the GM.")

Comment: @PeregrinTook Sure, but how far does *The wielder applies his Strength modifier to damage dealt by thrown weapons* go? When does the creature ever *stop* being that weapon's wielder? Until another creature throws it? I mean, there it says says *wielder* when we know the game means *attacker* lest absurdity ensue.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I added your comments to the question. I may close it if no conclusive answer rises.

Comment: (As an aside, *Pathfinder 2E* has a pretty darn clear definition of wield [here](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=194). I point to this because I don't want answers to confuse definitions between editions accidentally.)

Answer (score 5):

The *spell storing* special ability can only be placed on melee (= handheld) weapons. This restriction strongly suggests that the ability is meant to function only with melee attacks and that holding the weapon in one’s hand is a requirement to make the magic work.

A dagger that is thrown effectively becomes a thrown weapon. If a thrown dagger could deliver the stored spell it would mean, that holding the weapon in one’s hand *isn’t* a requirement to make the magic work.
But why can the spell storing ability only be placed on melee weapons and not also on thrown weapons? Why can a dagger be enchanted but not a dart? This restriction would not make sense then.

Therefore, I think it is coherent to assume – at least in this case - that wielding a weapon means holding that weapon in your hand and that you are no longer that weapon's wielder as soon as it leaves your hand. Following this, a hurled spell storing dagger can’t cast its stored spell, because it has "lost contact".

Comment: Nicely argued counterpoint. I wouldn't rule that way, but you make a good case, +1.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, you remain the "wielder" when you throw a melee weapon.

I would rule in favor of allowing you to activate the spell on a damaging hit with your thrown spell-storing dagger based on the following quote from the *Thrown Weapons* section of the weapons rules:

> **Thrown Weapons:** The wielder applies his Strength modifier to damage dealt by thrown weapons (except for splash weapons).

The user of a thrown weapon is explicitly defined by the rules as a "wielder." In fact, this sentence defines the thrower as a "wielder" in the context of what happens *after the weapon had left his hand* (i.e., the damage roll). To me, this implies that you remain the wielder of a thrown weapon through impact and damage. This should then allow the wielder to trigger the stored spell, which happens *immediately* upon the damage roll for which the thrower is still considered the wielder.

The rules are not entirely clear, and reasonable people might disagree with me, but this is how I would rule it.